# How to instantiate all property objects as well when Object.create is called?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a card object which i am trying to use as a class.

```
var Card = {
    image: new Image(),
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    setImage: function(ii){

        this.image.src = "assets/" + ii;


    }

};
```

I then instantiate the above "class" as:

```
var card = Object.create(Card);
card.setImage(cardsNames[i]);
```

It seems like Object.create() will create an instance of the object but inside it will not create unique image object.

For example

If i create two cards

```
var card1 = Object.create(Card);
card1.setImage(cardsNames[0]);

var card2 = Object.create(Card);
card2.setImage(cardsNames[1]);
```

here both card1.image and card2.image will point to same Image() object. How can i make it so that when i instantiate the object via Object.create() the object inside will also be duplicated? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an instantiable function with the [`new` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). This creates a new instance and separates the data.

```js
function Card() {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.x = 0;
    this.y = 0;
    this.setImage = function (ii) {
        this.image.src = "assets/" + ii;
    };
};

var card1 = new Card,
    card2 = new Card;

card1.setImage(42);
console.log(card1.image); // <img src="assets/42"></img> with source
console.log(card2.image); // <img></img>                 no source
```

Comment: are you suggesting this way is better than the Object.create method to instantiate objects? I was just following doug crockford avoid new suggestion.

Comment: for this purpose, yes. it is a plain OOP concept.

Comment: Back to the future… ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken Nina's answer 1 step further, just by making the "class" (function) an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) so that you have proper private functions in there.

```
var Card = (function () {

    var card = function () {
      this.image = new Image();
      this.x = 0;
      this.y = 0;  
    };

    card.prototype.setImage = function(ii) {
        this.image.src = "assets/" + ii;
    }

    return card;

})();

var cardsNames = ['1', '2'];

var card1 = new Card();
card1.setImage(cardsNames[0]);

var card2 = new Card();
card2.setImage(cardsNames[1]);

console.log(card1.image.src, card2.image.src);
```

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/HWTNI1ZU8aaiN98RymdJ?p=preview)

So some points to take away from this kind of design. The IIFE creates a new scope, therefore everything outside of it can't access things in it. e.g.

```
var Card = (function () {
   function log(message) {
       console.log(message);
   }
})();

log(); // undefined, not allowed, doesn't exist in this scope.
```

This does give you the ability to create private functions that can only be used in that scope.

Other than that, it is the same as Nina's suggestion. However, with the introduction of ES6/7 (2015/2017) etc... I think you'll be very rarely doing this.

Comment: sorry i am little new to javascript good practices. can you explain the benefits of this type of class design? does this improve on the previous version in that now the properties are private and cannot be accessed from outside?

Comment: This is functionally identical to Nina Scholz's answer, with more typing. :-/ Though at least the *setImage* function is inherited.